# Tkinter calling function in class through class variable

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am using Tkinter and trying to call a function within a class, but not getting it to work properly.

```
class Access_all_elements:

        def refSelect_load_file(self): 

            self.reffname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("XML files", "*.xml"),
                                                       ("All files", "*.*") ))
            if self.reffname:
                fileOpen = open(self.reffname)

        refSelect = Button(topFrame, text="Open Reference File", 
                    command=lambda:refSelect_load_file(self), bg = "yellow")
        refSelect.grid(row =1, column=1)
```

**Error:**

On executing above command, on pressing the button I get following error:

```
NameError: global name 'refSelect_load_file' is not defined
```

**What I tried:**

I tried calling a function using tkinter's generic approach which is not working for me.

```
refSelect = Button(topFrame, text="Open Reference File", 
                        command=refSelect_load_file, bg = "yellow")
refSelect.grid(row =1, column=1)
```

This throws me error:

```
TypeError: refSelect_load_file() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Can you guys suggest me something here?

Comment: It seems unusual to me to create widgets in the class scope, rather than inside a method in the class, such as `__init__`. If you were in a method, you could do `command=self.refSelect_load_file`.

Comment: @Kevin Thanks, I didn't know that. I will try it now.

Comment: @Digvijayad Hey i tried it, but button got disappeared. after putting entire code in `_init_`

Comment: Your code shows `refSelect_load_file` (lowercase leading "r") but the error message shows `RefSelect_load_file` (uppercase leading "r")

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for pointing. In my code the naming of classes is not aligned properly. I was suggested in last post to use proper name structure for classes and function. so the error you see is from names I used in my code. Sorry for that. I edited my post though

Edit: it was you i see now that suggested in last post :) thanks for that.

Comment: Glad you got it working.. I have updated my code as well, where you don't need to explicitly call the button to get it working.

Comment: @Digvijayad This is good as well. I accepted your answer for better visibility of solution. Also, thank you! Kevin for suggesting a patch at first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem will be solved when you call the function using `self.`

```
refSelect = Button(topFrame, text="Open Reference File", 
                    command=self.refSelect_load_file, bg = "yellow")
```

**Edit**
Try this.

```
class Access_all_elements():
    def __init__(self):
        refSelect = Button(topFrame, text="Open Reference File", 
                command=lambda:self.refSelect_load_file, bg = "yellow")
        refSelect.grid(row =1, column=1)


    def refSelect_load_file(self): 

        self.reffname = askopenfilename(filetypes=(("XML files", "*.xml"),
                                                   ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if self.reffname:
            fileOpen = open(self.reffname)
```

**Final Edit**

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog


class Access_all_elements():

    def __init__(self):
        refSelect = Button(root, text="Open Reference File",command=self.refSelect_load_file, bg = "yellow")
        refSelect.grid(row =1, column=1)

    def refSelect_load_file(self): 
        self.reffname = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=(("XML files", "*.xml"), ("All files", "*.*") ))
        if self.reffname:
            fileOpen = open(self.reffname)

root = Tk()
Access_all_elements()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But `self` isn't a valid reference unless you're inside a method that has a `self` parameter. He's creating the button directly inside the class.

Comment: @digvijayad it throws error `'self' is not defined`

Comment: @Digvijayad my button disappeared now. I did same.

Comment: I forgot to put the `self.` in the edit... try it now. If there is error let me know the error.

Comment: It shows no error. but button from GUI is gone. It disappeared.

Comment: @Digvijayad no still not working. the button needs to be invoked from `_init_` somehow. I am still trying. There is no error shown. simply the button is disappeared

Comment: Hey I got the button working finally. I made a little change to Digvijayad answer. Here is the code http://paste.ofcode.org/33UPutFQUZq5kXEy6USbCnF